# Dictionary App for Android and Database Inquiry

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, dictionary

I've been browsing this site for answers and I have obtained some but I still cannot start with my project. I'm kinda at a loss here.

I have my thesis which is a dictionary application for android using the porter stemming algorithm.

My idea is to INPUT WORDS > STEM THE INPUT > SEARCH THE WORD DATABASE BASED ON THE 'STEMMED' WORD > RETURN RESULTS (If the stemmed word matched a word in the database, return its the word with its definition, if not, show something like "word not found")

The database should be saved on the device so wifi connection wont be necessary anymore just like the WordNet Dictionary App for android.

I think it is possible to do this project, isn't it?
I'm using Eclipse Juno.

Now my questions are:

1) Is my idea for my thesis possible?

2) What database should I use? I'm using sqliteman. Saves me time since it has GUI. I've been told SQLite is the best. But can I use MS Access with this one without making a server like what I've read from the other posts? (MSAccess would save me time I think since I already have a word database for msaccess [.accdb].)

Sorry for the long posts and questions. I'm a computer science student and just starting to learn Java and Eclipse. Just needed help to make sure I'm on the right track.

Thank you everyone! :)

-Jon

Comment: Follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application/9109728#9109728

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Your thesis is very possible. And I'd recommend sqlite for your database. You can opt to save the sqlite file or create the tables manually in your app. As for this process

> INPUT WORDS > STEM THE INPUT > SEARCH THE WORD DATABASE BASED ON THE
>   'STEMMED' WORD > RETURN RESULTS

Try this tut http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/119293/Using-SQLite-Database-with-Android

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the tutorial! It helps me a lot :)

Answer (score 4):

1. Yes.
2. You can not use MS Access on Android. The reason why you should use SQLite is that it is already installed on Android and there are libraries for using SQLite on Android.

Comment: How he can use MS Access on Android?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response :) Glad my idea is possible and thanks for clearing that up to me. So i have no other choice but to use SQLite. Thank you! :)